# Does the google play store strip unused resources from apk?

Tags: android, resources, google-play, apk, installation

Does google play analyze the device, which downloads an app and strip out the unused resources?

e.g: I have a tablet with hdpi and provide hdpi and mdpi. Does the downloaded apk file contain the mdpi? Are there some other size optimizations that are applied to the apk **after** the packaging.

Comment: Users get the same APK that you upload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Play does not modify your APK in any way.

Please note that things have changed since this question (and my original answer) were posted:

- If you provide Google with your signing certificate, you can let them sign your uploaded APKs for you. Apparently, the APK contents are not modified, just its signature.
- If you decide to submit your app as an app bundle, Google will sort of strip unused resources by deciding at install time what resources a particular device will use.

Comment: This answer is out of date, as On-depend App Bundles are now available via the Play Store : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9006925

Comment: Well, technically, it's still.correct: If you upload an APK, Play won't modify it. Though I agree things changed with the introduction of app bundles.

Comment: Well in that case, "technically", if you are using Google Play's app signing, then Google is modifying your APK when they sign your uploaded APK 